# Lucene TermQuery and QueryParser

Tags: java, lucene

I have 2 lucene queries:

1)

```
Term term = new Term(Properties.LUCENE_APPARTMENT_ADDRESS,address);
Query termQuery = new TermQuery(term);
TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(termQuery, 20);
```

and
2)

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, Properties.LUCENE_APPARTMENT_ADDRESS, analyzer);
Query query = queryParser.parse(address);
ScoreDoc[] queryResults = indexSearcher.search(query, 20).scoreDocs;
```

Why the first one returns 1 result where the 2nd returns nothing? (the address is one word or more)

Comment: How about posting the actual query string? The first form sidesteps the analyzer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `QueryParser`, it uses analyzer which does the same sequence of actions as when during the indexing (tokenization, lowercasing, stopwords, etc.).

When you use raw `TermQuery`, you need to do all these steps yourself.

I guess your analyzer does something special about `Properties.LUCENE_APPARTMENT_ADDRESS` and you are not when passing the address to `TermQuery` hence the search results discrepancy.